# Is Geopandas module not compatible with Python3.8?

Tags: geopandas, python-3.8

Quick and soft question: when using Python3.8, I could not import geopandas in a `v-env`. Has anyone faced the same error or do I have another problem I didn't identified -which is absolutely possible.

Thanks.

Comment: GeoPandas should be compatible with python 3.8. It works in my conda environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, geopandas works in python 3.8.

To install geopandas, strictly follow the instructions in the official website.

`conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas`

https://geopandas.org/install.html